# React Native: How to pass a props variable from other js file to app.js file

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, function, react-native

I am a new to react native programming.

Following is the code I am following:

App.js Code:

```
export default function App() {

  const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState();

  const startGameHandler = (selectedNumber) => {
    setUserNumber(selectedNumber);
  };


  let content =  <StartGameScreen onStartGame={userNumber} />;

  if(userNumber){
     content = <GameScreen userChoice = {startGameHandler}/>
  }
```

other js file:

```
let confirmedOutput;
    if (confirmed) {
        confirmedOutput = (
            <Card style = {styles.summaryContainer}>
                <Text>You Selected</Text>
                <NumberContainer>{selectedNumber}</NumberContainer>
                <Button title= "Start Game" color = {colors.primary} onPress = {() => props.onStartGame(selectedNumber)}/>
            </Card>
        );
    };
```

I want to transfer selectedNumber from other js file to App.js file but I am getting error as props.onStartGame is not a fuction.

Help me solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the StartGameScreen is the child component shown.

onStartGame is called as a function in the child but in App you're passing the state instead of a function to update the state.

To get selected number in the parent you need to lift the state up then pass it as a prop to the child.

Below is the rough code, I haven't been able to test it so it may need some tweaking.

```
export default function App() {

  const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState();
  const [selectedNumber, setSelectedNumber] = useState();

  const startGameHandler = (selectedNumber) => {
    setUserNumber(selectedNumber);
  };



  let content =  <StartGameScreen selectedNumber={selectedNumber} 
            onStartGame={(userNumber) =>setUserNumber(userNumber)} />;

  if(userNumber){
     content = <GameScreen userChoice = {startGameHandler}/>
  }
```

```
let confirmedOutput;
    if (confirmed) {
        confirmedOutput = (
            <Card style = {styles.summaryContainer}>
                <Text>You Selected</Text>
                <NumberContainer>{props.selectedNumber}</NumberContainer>
                <Button title= "Start Game" color = {colors.primary} 
                   onPress = {() => props.onStartGame({props.selectedNumber})}/>
            </Card>
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Context in App.js, and the update it's value from any other file or component in your react-native app.

Your App.js :

```js
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { Linking } from "react-native";

export const NumberContext = createContext(null);

console.disableYellowBox = true;
if (!__DEV__) {
  console.log = () => { };
}
const App = () => {
  const [numberData, setNumberData] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    
  }, []);
  
   const startGameHandler = (selectedNumber) => {
    setUserNumber(selectedNumber);
  };


  let content =  <StartGameScreen onStartGame={userNumber} />;

  if(userNumber){
  return (
     <NumberContext.Provider value={[numberData, numberData]}>              <GameScreen userChoice = {startGameHandler}/>           </NumberContext.Provider>
  );
     
  }

  
};

export default App;
```

Your other JS File : confirmedOutput;

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";

export default ConfirmOutput = props => {
  const [numberFromCtxt, setNumberFromCtxt] = useContext(UserContext);
  
if (confirmed) {
        confirmedOutput = (
            <Card style = {styles.summaryContainer}>
                <Text>You Selected</Text>
                <NumberContainer>{selectedNumber}</NumberContainer>
                <Button title= "Start Game" color = {colors.primary} onPress = {() => {props.onStartGame(selectedNumber)}; setNumberFromCtxt(selectedNumber) }/>
            </Card>
        );
    };
```